# Razor pay route payments using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, payment-gateway, razorpay

ive been using razor pays normal checkout feature

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
              var options = {
                  "key": "rzp_****_*********",
                  "amount": 10000,
                  "currency": "INR",
                  "name": "XYZ",
                  "description": "Payment For Appointment at XYZ Limited",
                  "image": "https://XYZ.in/public/theme/images/re-logo.png",

                  "handler": function (response) {
                      var payid = response.razorpay_payment_id;
                      $('#transaction_id').val(payid);
                      $('#paymentform').submit();


                  },
                  "prefill": {
                      "name": "Name",
                      "email": "Email"
                  },
                  "notes": {
                      "address": "note value"
                  },
                  "theme": {
                      "color": "#F37254"
                  }
              };
              var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
              document.getElementById('payonlinebutton').onclick = function (e) {
                  rzp1.open();
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
            </script>
```

But i want to use route payments now, and on razorpay's document they have only sample code for curl
Can anyone help me with php solution if there is any.

i got his document but the concept is not that clear

https://razorpay.com/docs/server-integration/php/usage/#route

Comment: What are you talking about, what you linked to is clearly PHP code, and not _just_ cURL.

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP SDK https://razorpay.com/docs/server-integration/php/ and call the function as per need